# Is there a URL builder that supports request parameter concatenation as well?

Tags: asp.net, parameters, httpwebrequest, request, webrequest

I want to achieve something like the following:

```
UrlBuilder ub = new UrlBuilder("http://www.google.com/search");
ub.Parameters.Add("q","request");
ub.Parameters.Add("sourceid","ie8");

string uri = ub.ToString(); //http://www.google.com/search?q=request&sourceid=ie8
```

Is there anything in .NET, or I will have to create my own?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Nothing exists that I know of. Here's something simple which does what you want. Usage would be:

```
        UrlBuilder ub = new UrlBuilder("www.google.com/search")
        .AddQuery("q", "request")
        .AddQuery("sourceid", "ie8");

        string url=ub.ToString();
```

==

Code is:

```
    public class UrlBuilder
    {
        private string _authority;
        private string _host;
        private int? _port;
        private Dictionary<string, object> _query = new Dictionary<string, object>();

        public UrlBuilder(string host)
            : this("http", host, null)
        {

        }
        public UrlBuilder(string authority, string host)
            : this(authority, host, null)
        {
        }
        public UrlBuilder(string authority, string host, int? port)
        {
            this._authority = authority;
            this._host = host;
            this._port = port;
        }

        public UrlBuilder AddQuery(string key, object value)
        {
            this._query.Add(key, value);
            return this;
        }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            string url = _authority + "://" + _host;
            if (_port.HasValue)
            {
                url += ":" + _port.ToString();
            }


            return AppendQuery(url);
        }

        private string AppendQuery(string url)
        {
            if (_query.Count == 0)
            {
                return url;
            }

            url += "?";
            bool isNotFirst = false;
            foreach (var key in this._query.Keys)
            {
                if (isNotFirst)
                {
                    url += "&";
                }
                url += HttpUtility.UrlEncode(key) + "=" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode(this._query[key].ToString());
                isNotFirst = true;
            }

            return url;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @Josh: +1 for the effort. You could also make the AddQuery a method of Uri or UriBuilder class (existing in framework) - just a suggestion.

Comment: Yep that would work as well, I was actually thinking this would wrap the UriBuilder, but for no particular reason I went this approach

Comment: Josh, I really appreciate your effort.
I will surely use it once.
This particular time I find the code I posted bellow more convenience with my needs.
Thanks, many!

Comment: @Shimmy: No problem I was bored and felt like coding something simple, good luck

Comment: thank you so much. 
i got an inspiration from your boring lol

Comment: Nice, but you can't have duplicate keys. This is rare situation, but it is allowed. Thanks for your code anyway :)

Comment: Not to hard to extend this to support multiple keys, we'll that as an exercise to the reader:-) But good point none-the less.

Comment: @JoshBerke, +1 for the fluent interface idea.

Comment: Thanks for code. I made some changes to your code based on my needs. Maybe someone will find them useful. :) http://pastebin.com/wjf5LDAM

Answer (score 1):

Does the [UriBuilder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uribuilder.query.aspx) class help?

It doesn't have any method to add querystring parameters. Look at Query property to set values.

EDIT: See [UriTemplate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uritemplate.aspx) class.

Comment: For your original question, I didn't find anything specific to you are looking for. Don't you need an & to join querystring parameters?

Comment: It looks like this is Microsoft's (half-hearted) attempt to implement the functionality that Shimmy is asking for, it just falls short of being usable.

Answer (score 1):

I developed my own, that's more suitable for my needs, thanks for your code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Collections.Specialized;

namespace Utils
{
    public class ParameterCollectionBuilder : NameValueCollection
    {
        #region NameValueCollection Implementation
        public ParameterCollectionBuilder() : base() { }
        public ParameterCollectionBuilder(string uri)
        {
            Init(uri);
        }
        public ParameterCollectionBuilder(Uri uri) : this(uri.OriginalString) { }
        public ParameterCollectionBuilder(NameValueCollection baseCollection)
        {
            foreach (string key in baseCollection.Keys) this[key] = baseCollection[key];
            Init(ToString());
        }
        /// <summary>
        /// 
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="baseCollection"></param>
        /// <param name="uri"></param>
        /// <remarks>Note: any existing params in the uri will override the params in the collection.</remarks>
        public ParameterCollectionBuilder(NameValueCollection baseCollection, string uri)
        {
            foreach (string key in baseCollection.Keys) this[key] = baseCollection[key];
            Init(uri);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// 
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="baseCollection"></param>
        /// <param name="uri"></param>
        /// <remarks>Note: any existing params in the uri will override the params in the collection.</remarks>
        public ParameterCollectionBuilder(NameValueCollection baseCollection, Uri uri) : this(baseCollection, uri.OriginalString) { }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return Prefix + Query + Suffix;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// 
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="name"></param>
        /// <param name="value"></param>
        /// <remarks>Overides existing values.</remarks>
        public new void Add(string name, object value)
        {
            Set(name, GetString(value));
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Add an array of key-value pairs separated by colon char ':'.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="names">Invalid items will be ignored.</param>
        public void AddRange(string[] names)
        {
            rangeFlag = true;
            for (int i = 0; i < names.Length; i++)
            {
                string item = names[i];
                item = item.Replace("?", "");
                item = item.Replace("&", "");
                item = item.Replace("=", ":");
                string[] pair = item.Split(':');
                if (pair.Length == 2) Set(pair[0], pair[1]);                
            }
            InitUri(FullString);
            rangeFlag = false;
        }

        public void AppendQueryString(string query)
        {
            Add(BuildCollection(query));
        }

        public void RemoveRange(string[] keys)
        {
            rangeFlag = true;
            foreach (string key in keys)
            {
                Remove(key);  
            } 
            InitUri(FullString);
            rangeFlag = false;
        }


        bool rangeFlag = false;
        public new void Set(string name, object value)
        {
            base.Set(name, GetString(value));
            if (!rangeFlag && Uri != null) InitUri(FullString);
        }

        public override void Remove(string name)
        {
            base.Remove(name);
            if (!rangeFlag && Uri != null) InitUri(FullString);
        }

        public override void Clear()
        {
            base.Clear();
            if (Uri != null) InitUri(FullString);
        }

        #endregion NameValueCollection Implementation

        static string ParseQuery(string uri)
        {
            string query = "";

            if (!uri.Contains('=')) return query;

            int
                start = 0,
                end = uri.Length;

            if (uri.Contains('?')) start = uri.IndexOf('?');
            if (uri.Contains(':')) end = uri.LastIndexOf(':');

            query = uri.Substring(start, (start < end ? end : uri.Length) - start);
            return query;
        }

        void Init(string uri)
        {
            if (Uri == null)
            {
                InitUri(uri);
            }
            OriginalQuery = ParseQuery(uri);
            int qIndex = string.IsNullOrEmpty(OriginalQuery) ? uri.Length : uri.IndexOf(OriginalQuery);
            Prefix = uri.Substring(0, qIndex);
            Suffix = uri.Substring(qIndex + OriginalQuery.Length);
            Merge(OriginalQuery);
        }

        void Merge(string query)
        {
            NameValueCollection col = BuildCollection(query);
            foreach (string key in col.Keys)
            {
                string value = col[key];
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(value)) this[key] = value;
            }
        }
        void InitUri(string uri)
        {
            try
            {
                Uri = new Uri(uri);
            }
            catch { }
        }

        static string GetString(object value)
        {
            return value is string ? value as string : value.ToString();
        }

        static NameValueCollection BuildCollection(string query)
        {
            NameValueCollection collection = new NameValueCollection();
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(query) || !query.Contains('=')) return new NameValueCollection();

            //Prepare string
            query = query.ToLower();
            if (!query.StartsWith("?"))
            {
                if (query.Contains('?')) query = query.Substring(query.IndexOf('?'));
            }
            query = query.Replace("?", "");

            foreach (string pair in query.Split('&'))
            {
                string[] separated = pair.Split('=');
                if (separated.Length == 2) collection[separated[0]] = separated[1];
            }

            return collection;
        }

        static string BuildQuery(NameValueCollection parameters)
        {
            string query = "";
            Char separator = '?';
            bool first = true;
            foreach (string key in parameters.Keys)
            {
                query += string.Format("{0}{1}={2}", separator, key, parameters[key]);
                if (first)
                {
                    first = false;
                    separator = '&';
                }
            }
            return query;
        }

        #region Properties
        public Uri Uri { get; private set; }

        public string Prefix { get; private set; }
        public string OriginalQuery { get; private set; }
        public string Suffix { get; private set; }
        public string OriginalString
        {
            get
            {
                return Prefix + OriginalQuery + Suffix;
            }
        }
        public string Query
        {
            get
            {
                return BuildQuery(this);
            }
        }
        public string FullString
        {
            get
            {
                return ToString();
            }
        }
        #endregion Properties
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend you take a look at [this](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/UrlBuilder.aspx) article on CodeProject.

The author has extended the [System.UriBuilder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uribuilder.aspx) class and added a QueryString property that behaves in much the same way as the [HttpRequest.QueryString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.querystring.aspx) property.

Using this class your example would become:

```
UrlBuilder ub = new UrlBuilder("http://www.google.com/search");
ub.QueryString.Add("q", "request");
ub.QueryString.Add("sourceid", "ie8");
string uri = ub.ToString(); //http://www.google.com/search?q=request&sourceid=ie8
```

It doesn't have a [fluent interface](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fluent_interface) like [Josh's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/908507/is-there-a-url-builder-that-supports-request-paramater-concatenation-as-well/908552#908552) but could be easily extended to include one.

Comment: The code in that article isn't great.  It doesn't do any encoding/decoding of query string values.  So you're bound to run into trouble with it.

Answer (score 0):

With [Flurl](http://tmenier.github.io/Flurl) [disclosure: I'm the author], your example would look like this:

```
string uri = "http://www.google.com/search"
  .SetQueryParams(new { q = "request", sourceid = "ie8" });
```

The basic URL builder is available via NuGet:

`PM> Install-Package Flurl`

There's also a new companion lib that extends Flurl with [fluent](http://tmenier.github.io/Flurl/fluent-http), [testable](http://tmenier.github.io/Flurl/testable-http) HTTP:

`PM> Install-Package Flurl.Http`